# Добавить поддержку клавиатурного ввода в калькулятор

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как добавить возможность вводить цифры и математические операторы с клавиатуры применительно к нижеследующему коду? `.` и `,` должны восприниматься одинаково, например `(1.02 + 1,02 = 2.04)`.

```js
// Calculator script

$(function() {

  // Main variables
  var $screen = $('.screen');
  var value = 0;
  var start = true;
  var action = 0;

  // Display '0' on load
  $screen.text('0');

  // Digits
  $('.digit').on('click', function() {
    var mytext = $(this).text();
    var curtext = (start) ? '0' : $screen.text();
    start = false;
    if (mytext == '.') {
      if (curtext.indexOf('.') < 0) {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    } else {
      if (curtext === '0') {
        // Overwrite
        $screen.text(mytext);
      } else {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    }
  });

  // Maths operations
  function Maths_operations() {
    var num = parseFloat($screen.text());
    switch (action) {
      case 0:
        { // Nothing?
          value = num;
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        { // Add
          value += num;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        { // Subtract
          value -= num;
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        { // Multiply
          value *= num;
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        { // Divide
          if (num == 0) {
            value = 'Error'; // Couldn't divide by zero!
          } else {
            value /= num;
          }
        }
        break;
      default:
        break; // Shouldn't happen...
    }
    start = true; // New number now...
  }

  // Actions
  $('.action').on('click', function() {
    switch ($(this).text()) {
      case 'C':
        { // Clear
          value = 0;
          $screen.text('0');
          action = 0;
          start = true;
        }
        break;
      case '←':
        { // Delete last
          Maths_operations();
          action = 5;
        }
        break;
      case '\u00F7':
        { // Divide
          Maths_operations();
          action = 4;
        }
        break;
      case '\u00D7':
        { // Multiply
          Maths_operations();
          action = 3;
        }
        break;
      case '-':
        { // Subtract
          Maths_operations();
          action = 2;
        }
        break;
      case '+':
        { // Add
          Maths_operations();
          action = 1;
        }
        break;
      case '=':
        { // Equals
          Maths_operations();
          $screen.text(value);
          action = 0; // Nothing
        }
        break;
      default:
        { // If it's not a button
          console.log($(this).text());
        }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
/* Basic reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  /* Global text styling */
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Background */
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(171, 168, 168, 0.82);
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Name */
.pre-top > span {
  display: block;
  
  /* Special text styling */
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', Monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.pre-top .version {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* Calculator body */
.calculator {
  
  /* Absolute horizontal & vertical centering */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 9px;
  background: #b8c6cc;
  background: linear-gradient(#979fa2 14.9%, #6a7073 52.31%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  /* Using box shadows to create 3D effects */
  box-shadow: 0 4px #5e6264, 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Top */
.top span.clear {
  float: left;
}

.top .screen {
  height: 40px;
  width: 212px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /* Inset shadow on the screen to create some indent */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Typography */
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* Clear floats */
.keys,
.top {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Applying same to the keys */
.keys span,
.top span.clear,
.top span.backspace {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 66px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 8px 11px 0;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
 
  /* Smoothing out hover and active states using css3 transitions */
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  /* Prevent selection of text inside keys in all browsers*/
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.keys span {
  width: 84px;
}

/* Style different type of keys (operators/evaluate/clear) differently */
.keys span.operator {
  background: #f5ac75;
  /* Remove right margins from operator keys */
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.keys span.eval {
  background: #79de9e;
  color: #fff;
}

.top span.clear,
.top span.backspace {
  background: #e79199;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Some hover effects */
.keys span:hover {
  background: #7d8ae3;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #5963a0;
  color: #fff;
}

.keys span.operator:hover {
  background: #fa9345;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #ce8248;
}

.keys span.eval:hover {
  background: #39f788;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #2fc66e;
  color: #fff;
}

.top span.clear:hover,
.top span.backspace:hover {
  background: #f86670;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #d5656d;
}

/* Simulating "pressed" effect on active state of the keys by removing the box-shadow and moving the keys down a bit */
.keys span:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #6b54d3;
}

.keys span.eval:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #717a33;
}

.top span.clear:active,
.top span.backspace:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #d3545d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Some Google Fonts -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab|Roboto+Mono:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Calculator -->
<div class="calculator">

  <!-- Name -->
  <div class="pre-top">
    <span class="name">jQuery calculator</span>
    <span class="version">v1.1</span>
  <div>

  <!-- Clear key & screen-->
  <div class="top">
    <span class="action clear">C</span>
    <span class="action backspace">←</span>
    <span class="screen"></span>
  </div>

  <!-- Operators and other keys -->
  <div class="keys">
    <span class="digit">7</span>
    <span class="digit">8</span>
    <span class="digit">9</span>
    <span class="action operator">+</span>
    <span class="digit">4</span>
    <span class="digit">5</span>
    <span class="digit">6</span>
    <span class="action operator">-</span>
    <span class="digit">1</span>
    <span class="digit">2</span>
    <span class="digit">3</span>
    <span class="action operator">&divide;</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">.</span>
    <span class="action eval">=</span>
    <span class="action operator">&times;</span>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvzqrL) версия. Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: Мило. Надо будет что-нибудь похожее реализовать через fxlpp (библиотека, прослойка между Xlib и кодером)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделить обработчик нажатия на кнопки и их функционал.

В данном коде это обработка чисел:

```
  $('.digit').on('click', function() {
    var mytext = $(this).text();
    digitAction(mytext);
  });

  function digitAction(mytext)
  {
    var curtext = (start) ? '0' : $screen.text();
    start = false;
    if (mytext === '.') {
      if (curtext.indexOf('.') < 0) {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    } else {
      if (curtext === '0') {
        // Overwrite
        $screen.text(mytext);
      } else {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    }
  }
```

И обработка событий:

```
  $('.action').on('click', function() {
    doAction($(this).text());
  });
  function doAction(op)
  {

    switch (op) {
      case 'C':
        {
          value = 0;
          $screen.text('0');
          action = 0;
          start = true;
        }
        break;
      case '\u00F7':
        { // Divide
          Maths_operations();
          action = 4;
        }
        break;
      case '\u00D7':
        { // Multiply
          Maths_operations();
          action = 3;
        }
        break;
      case '-':
        { // Subtract
          Maths_operations();
          action = 2;
        }
        break;
      case '+':
        { // Add
          Maths_operations();
          action = 1;
        }
        break;
      case '=':
        { // Equals
          Maths_operations();
          $screen.text(value);
          action = 0; // Nothing
        }
        break;
      default:
        { // If it's not a button
          console.log($(this).text());
        }
    }
  }
```

Остается только добавить обработчик ввода с клавиатуры и передавать символы в отделенной функционал. Ну и добавить замену ',' на '.'.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    console.log(char)
    switch(char)
    {
      case '0':
      case '1':
      case '2':
      case '3':
      case '4':
      case '5':
      case '6':
      case '7':
      case '8':
      case '9':
      case '.':
      case ',':
        if(char == ',') char = '.';
        digitAction(char);
        break;
      case '-':
      case '+':
      case '=':
      case '/':
      case '*':
      case 'C':
        doAction(char);
        break;
    }
  });
```

[Codepen fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BowjBj) версия.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность! А можно, пожалуйста, добавить действия и экшен на клавишу `backspace` чтобы она удаляла посимвольно числа если в нём больше чем один знак и точку если это дробное число, а также `Enter` чтобы работал как `=`?

Answer (score 2):

Вешаете событие `keyup`
Далее в объекте события у вас будет возможность получить код нажатой кнопки `e.keyCode`

[Тут](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) таблица кодов и их значений, какому коду, какая кнопка соответствует.

Далее уже имея все эти данные можете для каждой нажатой кнопки выполнять необходимое действие.